# Poetic synonym for Garden

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, poésie

Disclaimer: I'm not a french speaker.

I'm writing a short story in which I want to use a french phrase for a beautifully manicured garden/arboretum, something which would mean something similar to "slice of heaven" or "piece of nature".

I tried to google but all I get are literal translations such as "coin de paradis" and "morceau de nature". I'm not sure how correct they are. Can anyone suggest a good poetic, descriptive phrase for it?

> Sample Sentence - This arboretum is my refuge, my home away from home,
>   my "french phrase".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Mon morceau de nature* wouldn't work but ***mon petit coin de paradis*** would be just fine.

Comment: "mon petit coin de paradis" -> that means "My little slice of heaven", correct ? Although, to be honest, it sounds like a mouthful, is there something more...umm, concise?

Comment: Literally, yes, or maybe *my little "nook" of heaven*.

Comment: This phrase sounds fine in French and is idiomatic. I don't think about anything more concise, maybe just *mon petit paradis*.